# ProgressBar is not set visible before other operations by click button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, visibility, android-progressbar

I work with `MediaPlayer` and want to show `ProgressBar` before calling method `mediaPlayer.prepare()` (it can take up some time). I tried `AsynkTast, Thread, Handler` but it is show progressBar only after all operations at the end of `clickPlayButton` method. What I do wrong?
Thanks!

ProgressBar declaration:

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

clickPlayButton method

```
public void clickPlayButton(View view) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          h.post(updateProgress);
        }
    });
    t.start();
 //  progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
   // new ProgressTask().execute();

    mTimer = new Timer();
    mMyTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
       btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_stop);
       try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(DATA_HTTP);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
           }
       catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

       mediaPlayer.start();
       mTimer.schedule(mMyTimerTask, 10, 5000);
    }
    else {
          btnPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.player_play);
          mediaPlayer.pause();
          mTimer.cancel();
         }
  //  progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}

Handler h = new Handler();
Runnable updateProgress = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

Comment: Is your clickPlayButton() inside an asyncTask or it's running on the main thread?

EDIT : Looks like it's inside the MainActivity.
May I ask as to why you are creating threads for hiding the displaying the progress bar?
You can simply call the `progressBar.setVisibility` method on the main thread directly too.

Comment: It is in Main thread. if I try just 'progressBar.setVisibility' i have the same result.